# How do I override the subscription block?

Tags: 8, emails

I am developing a Drupal 8 website and I want to override the subscription block used by the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module. I know how to achieve that at Drupal 7, but the module is different now. For Drupal 7, I followed http://api.worldempire.ch/api/simplenews/theme%21simplenews-block.tpl.php/7-2.

I want to do the same for Drupal 8. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you trying to override the template file or something more complicated?

Comment: I want to override the template file but if you have a better solution, you can suggest it.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact equivalent currently. To override the actual block template for that block you can use 'block--simplenewssubscription.html.twig'. You can use the input and form templates to override other elements. I would suggest enabling debugging in Twig so you can see the template overrides.